# Does the law of large numbers hold when $\epsilon_n\rightarrow 0$?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $Y_n\sim \text{Pois}(n)$.I need to find for each $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ the limit $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(Y_n\geq n+n^\alpha)$$

I got to:

$$P(Y_n\geq n+n^\alpha)=P\left(\frac {Y_n} n -1 \geq n^{\alpha-1}\right)\leq P\left(\left|\frac {Y_n} n -1\right| \geq n^{\alpha-1}\right)$$

This is the CLT for $Y_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ where $X_i\sim\text{Pois}(1)$ and $\mu=1$. For a fixed $\epsilon$, we have by the law of large numbers that $$P\left(\left|\frac {Y_n} n -1\right| \geq \epsilon\right)\rightarrow 0$$

Back to the question, for any $\alpha\geq 1$ we get the limit equals $0$. But when $\alpha< 1$, $n^{\alpha-1}\rightarrow 0$ and I don't think the law of large numbers hold anymore (I am not sure what is the formal explanation to this).

Can I please get an explanation to:

1. Does the law of large numbers $$P\left(\left|\frac {S_n} n -\mu\right| \geq \epsilon_n\right)\rightarrow 0$$ hold when $\epsilon_n\rightarrow 0$?
2. In the specific problem presented, what is the limit when $\alpha<1$? Infinity?

Comment: Have you tried Chebyshevs inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the central limit theorem, not the law of large numbers.
Define $Z_n=(Y_n-n)/\sqrt{n}$ so that $Z_n$ converges to a standard normal in distribution as $n\to\infty$. Now $$P(Y_n\geq n+n^\alpha)=P(Z_n\geq n^{\alpha-1/2}).$$ You will find three different limits, depending on whether $\alpha>1/2$, $\alpha=1/2$, or $\alpha<1/2$.